# How to find a string value in the radgrid by FindItemByKeyValue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, radgrid

Hi there i have a radgrid on which i have to find a value and if the item is found then generate  message

below is my code

```
Protected Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        If IsAlreadyExist() Then
            ram.Alert("")
        Else
            If IsAlreadyAdded() Then
                ram.Alert("")
            Else
                employees()
            End If


        End If
    End Sub
```

and here is the IsAlreadyAdded mehtod in which iam trying to find a specific value in grid   if it exists it will return false

```
Private Function IsAlreadyAdded() As Boolean
        'If rgListnk.MasterTableView.Items.Count > 0 Then
        Dim itm As GridDataItem = rgList.MasterTableView.FindItemByKeyValue("DEFAULT", "Y")

        If IsNothing(itm) Then
            Return False
        Else
            Return True
        End If

    End Function
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through each row of the Grid in order to find a value of a cell.

Make sure **DataKeyNames** is specified if you want to find item by **FindItemByKeyValue**.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server"
    OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource">
    <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="Id">
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1"
    OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" />

public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender,
        GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        RadGrid1.DataSource = new List<User>
        {
            new User {Id = 1, FirstName = "Jon", LastName = "Doe"},
            new User {Id = 2, FirstName = "Marry", LastName = "Doe"},
            new User {Id = 3, FirstName = "Eric", LastName = "Newton"},
        };
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var firstItem = RadGrid1.MasterTableView.FindItemByKeyValue("Id", 1);
        if (firstItem != null)
        {
            var firstName = firstItem["FirstName"].Text;
            var lastName = firstItem["lastName"].Text;
        }

        foreach (GridItem item in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items)
        {
            if (item is GridDataItem)
            {
                var dataItem = item as GridDataItem;
                var firstName = dataItem["FirstName"].Text;
                var lastName = dataItem["lastName"].Text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply .why i cant do it by .FindItemByKeyValue() any specific reason ?

Comment: I updated the answer. Make sure **MasterTableView**'s **DataKeyNames** is specified (in your case it is **DEFAULT**).